# Runtime error: reference binding to null pointer of type 'int' (stl_vector.h) while dealing with leetcode test cases

Tags: c++, vector

> SUMMARY: UndefinedBehaviorSanitizer: undefined-behavior
> /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../../include/c++/9/bits/stl_vector.h:1043:9

was the remainder of the error message.

I have been working to solve the Merge 2 sorted arrays problem (https://leetcode.com/explore/learn/card/fun-with-arrays/525/inserting-items-into-an-array/3253/) for the past hour, using the vector insert function as below:

```
class Solution {
public:
    void merge(vector<int>& nums1, int m, vector<int>& nums2, int n) {
        int j=0;
        if(nums1.empty() || nums1.size()==1){
            nums1.push_back(nums2[0]);
            return;
        }
        if(nums2.empty()){
            return;
        }
        
        
        for(int i=0; i<(m+n); i++){
            if(j<n){
                if(nums1[i]<nums2[j] && nums1[i+1] >= nums2[j]){
                    nums1.insert(nums1.begin()+i+1, nums2[j]);
                    j++;
                }
                if(nums1[i]<nums2[j] && nums1[i+1]==0){
                    nums1.insert(nums1.begin()+i+1, nums2[j]);
                    j++;
                }
            }
          cout << j;
        }
        int size = nums1.size()-1;
        if(nums1.size()>1){
        int resiz = m+n;
        nums1.resize(resiz);
      }
        return;
    }
};
```

I have got to the right solution using this. I have to resize at the end to get rid of the trailing 0s since the insert() method increases the vector size each time.

The problem lies in the test case

[1]         // contents of array 1

1           // size of vct 1

[]          // contents of array 2

0           // size of vct 2

Of course there may be better ways to solve the problem (and I'd appreciate those suggestions), but I'd like to understand what's causing this, since I have explicitly tried to deal with these edge cases in code.

Comment: What is your actual question?

Comment: How do I get rid of the error? I though it was clear enough

Comment: In the testcase you mentioned the size of nums1 is 1 so the condition for `if(nums1.empty() || nums1.size() == 1)` satisfies and in the `if` the code is `nums1.push_back(nums2[0])` but the problem is the size of nums2 is 0 i.e. nums2[0] is undefined befaviour

Comment: Thanks @susanth29 I'll try to make that change, I'll filter out the empty nums2 before i get to that case

Comment: what if the elements of nums2 are smaller than the first element of nums1?

Comment: At what point in your code is the error triggered? A debugger should make this easy to find; without a debugger, diagnostics streamed to `std::cerr` can still be used.

Answer (score 1):

### Your solution

The only edge case is `m=0` which should easily be handled by setting `nums1=nums2`. Aside from that, there are a few logic bugs presented in your code. I have put comments besides the lines I changed.

```
class Solution {
    public:
    void merge(vector<int>& nums1, int m, vector<int>& nums2, int n) {
        int j=0;
        if(m==0){ //edge case
            nums1 = nums2;
            return;
        }
        constexpr int IMPOSSIBLE = int(1e9+1);
        for (int i=m; i<n+m; i++) {
            // initialize it to an "impossible" value instead of 0 which could be a valid value!
            nums1[i]=IMPOSSIBLE; 
        }
        for(; j<n; j++){ // handle element in nums2 smaller than nums[0] first
            if(nums2[j]<=nums1[j]){
                nums1.insert(nums1.begin()+j,nums2[j]);
            } else {
                break;
            }
        }
        for(int i=0; i<(m+n); i++){
            if(j<n){
                if(nums1[i]<=nums2[j] && i+1<int(nums1.size()) && nums1[i+1] >= nums2[j]){
                    // The correct logic should be nums1[i]<=nums2[j](e.g. nums1=[1,0,0],n=1,nums2=[2,2],m=2)
                    nums1.insert(nums1.begin()+i+1, nums2[j]);
                    j++;
                } else if(nums1[i]<=nums2[j] && i+1<int(nums1.size()) && nums1[i+1]==IMPOSSIBLE){ 
                    /*
                    1. The correct logic should be nums1[i] <=nums2[j], 
                    but since IMPOSSIBLE is initialized to the largest value possible, 
                    either < and <= will work here.
                    2. You must use elseif here, otherwise j may be incremented! 
                    3. 0 does not mean empty cause it could be the real value in nums1[i+1]
                    */
                    nums1.insert(nums1.begin()+i+1, nums2[j]);
                    j++;
                }
            }
        }
        int size = nums1.size()-1;
        if(nums1.size()>1){
            int resiz = m+n;
            nums1.resize(resiz);
        }
        return;
    }
};
```

### Suggestions

Merging two sorted arrays is a very well-known and standard problem. The canonical way is to use [two pointers](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/merge-two-sorted-arrays/). It will be much cleaner and I highly advise you to read about it.

An even cleaner approach is to use [`std::merge`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/merge) provided by C++ STL which achieves exactly the same purpose, although it might be a bit... cheaty for your purpose? (I assume you are learning algorithms)

```
class Solution {
    public:
    void merge(vector<int>& nums1, int m, vector<int>& nums2, int n) {
        vector<int> nums3;
        nums3.reserve(n+m);
        std::merge(nums1.begin(), nums1.begin()+m, nums2.begin(), nums2.begin(), std::back_inserter(nums3));
        nums1=nums3;
        return;
    }
};
```

Both solutions above takes O(n+m) time, while your solution is O((n+m)*m), as `std::vector::insert` takes O(n+m) time